# What is the counting argument for the number of elementary operations required for a random function?

Tags: complexity-theory, classical-computing, random-quantum-circuit

What is the counting argument for the following statement (classical)?

"A random function on n bits requires $e^{\Omega(n)}$ elementary operations."

It appears in the introduction of PRL 116, 170502 (2016): [Efficient Quantum Pseudorandomness](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/115397/PhysRevLett.116.170502.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Is it that since there are infinitely many n-bit boolean functions, implementing one such randomly chosen function using elementary operations would require an exponentially large number? (I'm assuming that elementary operations here mean two-bit universal gates.)

Also, why $\Omega(n)$ and not $O(n)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\Omega(n)$ generally means lower bound, while $O(n)$ means upper bound, does that answer your question? Also, there are $2^n$ boolean functions, not an infinite number.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I somehow missed the **Boolean** part. So, $2^n=e^{ln 2^n} \approx e^{\Omega(n)}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that a function $f(n)$ is $O(n)$ if its *bounded above* by $n$ asymptotically, which is not to be confused with a function $f(n)$ being $\Omega(n)$ which means that $f(n)$ is *bounded below* by $n$ asymptotically.

Also, there are $2^n$ boolean functions on $\{0,1\}^n$ since each boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is in one-to-one correspondence with a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ via the identification $f^{-1}(1)=S$.

So like you said in the comments $2^n=e^{\Omega(n)}$.